# How can add other group series in google chart

Tags: google-visualization

i have a problem, i need to put in 1 chart multiple data, but i dont know how to do it, i see examples of column bar, but this is always with 2 series.

what i need to do is something like this...

```
(Serie1)
TotalXmLCargados = 503
TotalCasosCreados = 501
TotalCasosEscaneados = 402

(Serie2)
TotalLicenciasLica = 402
TotalLicenciasEscaneadas =503

(Serie3)
TotalCasosEscaneados = 403
TotalCasosClasificados = 705
```

HOw i can do this in 1 chart???

it is possible?

I found a example of what i need, heres the link of the image.
http://libweb.surrey.ac.uk/library/skills/Number%20Skills%20Leicester/images/pic030.gif

Comment: Isn;t this the exact chart you want? https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#creating-material-column-charts, just renaming your categories ... call them category1, category 2 and category 3 since you seen to have really 7 different categories in your example

Comment: but it is possible to have a year with 4 categories and the other year with 2 categories ?